# least squares equation for a vertical line

Tags: least-squares

Given the following 2d points:

213 106.8

214 189

214 293.4

213 324

223 414

I want to find an equation for the least squares vertical axis line that runs through them. My plan is to get a line equation so I can test subsequent points for their distances to that least squares line.

Thanks

Comment: no, this is not homework, I'm making a facial recognition program and this is a small aspect of it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a least squares fit is not defined for a vertical line (since
the error for each point is measured parallel to the Y axis).

However, if you swap X and Y, you can find the horizontal line with the best least
squares fit.  It works out to simply the mean of the Y coordinate values:

The equation for a horizontal line is simply y = b.

The error at each point  (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) is (y<sub>i</sub> - b).

The sum of the squares of the errors is SSE = sum( (y<sub>i</sub> - b)<sup>2</sup>).  We wish
to find the value of b that minimizes SSE.  Take the partial derivative of SSE with
respect to b and set it to zero:

sum(-2(y<sub>i</sub> - b)) = 0

Simplifying,

sum(y<sub>i</sub>) - Nb = 0

and

b = sum(y<sub>i</sub>)/N

So in your case, averaging the X coordinates gives you the X coordinate of
the vertical line that best fits your points.

Answer (score 4):

The most generic solution would be to apply [Total Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares)

This finds (a, b, d) to minimize the sum of squared perpendicular distances (ax+by=d (a^2+b^2=1): |ax + by – d|). This can handle vertical lines, such as 0x+1y=0.

However, this is a bit more difficult to implement, so the solution offered by @Jim Lewis might be fine and more practical..

Comment: I'm not sure what language OP is working with, but this is implemented in [scipy-ODR](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html). To do it, one must [use two-dimensional input data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508510/804329) (one dimension is x, the other is y) and then the model value is zero. So you're solving, as you say, the minimization of ax+by+d=0.

Comment: 0x+1y=0 is not vertical, it is a horizontal line.

Comment: Does this work if all points reside exactly on the same vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line of best fit to be vertical (i.e. x = constant), the y-values are irrelevant. Simply take the square root of the mean of the squares of the x-values.

Comment: but if they can be only positive (like in case of pixels)? ^^